# How can we improve our site tour?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

Our site tour is currently generic, using the audience and topic description from Area 51 without customization.  I also noticed that the on-topic list there includes "Specific issues with building, administering, managing and cultivating digital communities", but we've said we're not just for *digital* communities but *all* communities.

We're having trouble attracting a core, and while this isn't the only thing we need to fix by far, I suspect that the tour -- the very first thing a new visitor is presented with -- isn't helping.  So, how can we improve it?  The customizations available to our moderators are:

- the opening paragraph
- the "ask about" and "don't ask about" lists -- we could do with some more specific entries on the former
- the sample question, if any question on the site meets the requirements (I don't know if we have any questions that do; the mods would have to tell us what if anything is on the "eligible" list right now)

Comment: No eligible questions for the sample question.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin thanks.  I was afraid of that.

Comment: I really wish that the criteria was less specific for beta sites and/or there was a specific requirement for a post. I guess the nature of our site has long questions/answers, so that doesn't work out well when it usually likes short questions.

Comment: Yeah, not just here -- the questions and answers we want to hold up as good examples, all across the network, tend to be longer and supported by relevant quotes, citations, and in some cases diagrams.

Comment: I agree we can improve it, but would need some ideas on how.  I've been more or less a ghost the last week or two and will be for another week or so as I've been in the middle of a move.  But if someone can write up some suggestions, I can at least squeeze in commenting if I see anything missing.

Comment: @AJHenderson I'm hoping this question will elicit some specific suggestions.  I'm not expecting the mods to read minds; let's all figure out how to make this better.

Answer (score 3):

> ### Draft for [Tour Page](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tour):
>
> ***Ask about:***

- Creating, expanding, and cultivating communities, their content, and the relationships among members
- Issues caused by members with different expectations, backgrounds, or tolerances
- Questions about both online and offline communities
- Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

> ***Don't ask about:***

- Anything not directly related to building, administering, managing and cultivating communities
- Questions that are primarily opinion-based
- Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

Answer (score 3):

> ### Draft for [Top of Tour](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tour):

**Community Building Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for community managers, administrators, leaders, moderators, and sociologists. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about building, administering, managing and cultivating online and offline communities.

Comment: I don't know if "sociologists" is the right group to call out, but I want to *somehow* reflect "people who are interested in how groups of people work".  Improvements welcome!

Comment: @MonicaCellio is there really that many people who are interested in the abstract concept how groups interact that participate on this site? I think people are only interested for practical reasons, thus the leaders an moderators covers that in my opinion.

Comment: "s there really that many people who are interested in the abstract concept how groups interact that participate on this site" -- who already participate here, no.  Who would be valuable participants if we could lure them in, yes.  I could be mistaken, of course, but I think we want to write this paragraph to encourage the "oh hey that's me!" reaction if we can (so long as it doesn't become long and unwieldy).

Comment: That's why I said sociologists and not psychologists.  Sociologists study people in groups; that seems like a better fit.  If there's some other field that'd be better then I'm totally open to that; I just want to do *something* that reaches "out", so to speak, and isn't just about the folks (overwhelmingly, SE mods) who founded the community.